# How to test that Cursor is working properly

Tags: sql-server, database

I am working on SQL Server for long time but I never used Cursor. I got one project where they have used cursor and I have to Identify that each procedure, cursor, trigger is performing well and if there is any need to improvement.
I have done with all except cursor, how can I test that?

Comment: I think cursor is mostly bad for performance. you should search for alternatives.

Comment: Sure, I will dig more into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you know the concept of loop, same like we use Cursor to go row by
>   row. Suppose you have lots of records and you have also used cursor in
>   your query or in your stored procedure, it will mess up your
>   application performance.
>
> Suppose in any stored procedure you have used Cursor and you are
>   writing a stored procedure with Cursor that will call first stored
>   procedure, here you are using nested cursor and again your app
>   performance would be down here.  So think twice before using Cursor.

**Don't use until and unless its not required.**